# Computing limit involving integration (application of FTC)

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

The question asks:

> Let $f(x)$ be continuous with domain $\mathbb{R}$. Compute the following limit:
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{(x-t)f(t)}{x^2} \,dt$$

I sense I have to use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus somehow but I don't know how. Could anyone help? Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you been specifically asked to use FTC? The limit is $\frac {f(0)} 2$ and it is easy to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

The given  limit is just $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1 x \int_0^{x} f(t)dt-\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\int_0^{x} tf(t)dt} {x^{2}}$. The first limit is $f(0)$ by FTC. Now write $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\int_0^{x} tf(t)dt} {x^{2}}$$ $$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\int_0^{x} t[f(t)-f(0)]dt} {x^{2}}-\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\int_0^{x} tf(0)dt} {x^{2}}.$$ Write down the last limit by direct calculation. For showing that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\int_0^{x} t[f(t)-f(0)]dt} {x^{2}}=0$ use the fact that $|f(t)-f(0)| <\epsilon$ for all $t$ between $0$ and $x$ provided $|x|$ is suffciently small.

Comment: I thought I already answerd the same question earlier today but I cannot locate it now. Perhaps the question was deleted. I am sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: For the second integral we can put $t^2=u$ to get $\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x tf(t) \, dt=\frac{1}{2x^2}\int_0^{x^2}f(\sqrt{u})\,du$ which by FTC tends to $f(0)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{0}^{x} \frac{(x-t)f(t)}{x^2} \,dt = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{f(t)}{x} \,dt - \int_{0}^{x} \frac{tf(t)}{x^2} \,dt = \frac 1x \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt - \frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x} tf(t) \, dt
$$

Time to use FTC and the fact that antiderivative $F$ is not just continuous, but continuously differentiable for continuous $f$. Then it is possible to apply L'Hopital's rule. But firstly, it's better to integrate by parts:
$$
\int_{0}^{x} tf(t) \,dt \,dt = F(x)x - \int_{0}^{x} F(t) \,dt.
$$
So we get (assuming $F(0) = 0$)
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \left[\frac{F(x)}{x} - \frac{xF(x)}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x} F(t) \,dt \right] = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x} F(t) \,dt = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)}{2x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{2} = \frac{f(0)}{2},
$$
where L'Hopital's rule was used twice.

Answer (score 0):

As $x^2$ doesn't depend on $t$ I take it out of the integral
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^x f(t) (x-t) \, dt}{x^2}$$
Apply twice  L'Hopital rule
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^x f(t) \, dt}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{2}=\frac{f(0}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $ x\in\mathbb{R}^{*} $, notice that using the change of variable $ \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}t&=xy\\ \mathrm{d}t&=x\,\mathrm{d}y\end{aligned}\right. $, we get that : \begin{aligned} \frac{1}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}{\left(x-t\right)f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}&=\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)f\left(xy\right)\mathrm{d}y}\\&=\frac{f\left(0\right)}{2}+\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)\left(f\left(xy\right)-f\left(0\right)\right)\mathrm{d}y} \end{aligned}

Now let $ \varepsilon >0 $, since $ f $ is $ \mathcal{C}^{0} $ on $ \mathbb{R} $, then there exists some $ \eta >0 $ such that, for all $ x\in\left(-\eta,\eta\right) $, we have : $$ \left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right|<\varepsilon $$

That means if $ x $ was in $ \left(-\eta,\eta\right) $, then, since $ \left(\forall y\in\left[0,1\right]\right),\ xy\in\left(-\eta, \eta\right) $, we would have that $ \left|f\left(xy\right)-f\left(0\right)\right|<\varepsilon $.

Thus, if we let $ x\in\left(-\eta,\eta\right)\setminus\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace $, we'll get : \begin{aligned} \left\vert\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)\left(f\left(xy\right)-f\left(0\right)\right)\mathrm{d}y}\right\vert&\leq\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)\left\vert f\left(xy\right)-f\left(0\right)\right\vert\mathrm{d}y}\\ &\leq\varepsilon\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \end{aligned}

Hence : $$ \left\vert\frac{1}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}{\left(x-t\right)f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}-\frac{f\left(0\right)}{2}\right\vert\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$

Which proves that : $$ \frac{1}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}{\left(x-t\right)f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}\frac{f\left(0\right)}{2} $$